# Spring Boot with datasource when testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot application and the auto cofiguration is enabled. The main Application file is marked as `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. The datasource is lookedup from JNDI is configured using java config and the class which create the datasource is marked as `@Configuration`.

I have a test class as below.

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration( classes = Application.class )
public class TestSomeBusiness {}
```

The issue is when I run the test case, the datasource jndi lookup happens, which fails because the test case is not running inside a server environment. As far as I know the classes in classpath marked with `@Configuration` are executed and that the reason the datasource lookup is being called.

The work around for now I have found is instead of JNDI lookup create the datasource using `DriverManagerDataSource`, so that even if its not a server environment the datasource lookup won't fail.

My questions are:

1) How do we generally deal with datasource (when looking up from JNDI) in 
spring boot application for testing ?

2) Is there a way to exclude the datasource configuration class from being called when executing test case ?

3) Should I create an embedded server so that the JNDI lookup can be done when executing test case ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 2) Is there a way to exclude the datasource configuration class from being called when executing test case ?

You can add a `application.properties` config file into your `src/test/resources` and spring boot would pick those configurations in test environments. I suppose, you have `application.properties` in your `src/main/resources` like this:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=some_jndi
```

This `JNDI` resource will be used in your production environment. For your test environment you can use a, say MySQL database, by adding these configurations into your test `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

> 3) Should I create an embedded server so that the JNDI lookup can be
>   done when executing test case ?

As i said, you can totally bypass the fact that you're using `JNDI` for production by adding test specific configurations.

> 1) How do we generally deal with datasource (when looking up from
>   JNDI) in spring boot application for testing ?

You can mock `JNDI` resources using facilities available in `org.springframework.mock.jndi` package. For example by using `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` you can:

```
SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
builder.bind("jndi_name", dataSource);
builder.activate();
```

The other option is, of course, using `Non JNDI` resources in test environments.