# Make Spring JUnit Test run on test database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I would like to configure my JUnit Tests to run on a different database than the one the Application runs on. I've been doing this for hours but have had no success so far. Tried configuring it using the application.properties file and the spring config file but nothing worked. So how can this be accomplished? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.profiles.active=test")
public class TestContactController extends AbstractTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    @Rollback
    public void testAddContact() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/contact/add").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content("{\n" +
                    "\t\"authCode\": \"daca824a0bf04d038543373adfdb2c8f\",\n" +
                    "\t\"requestData\":{\n" +
                    "\t\t\"firstName\": \"Max\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\"lastName\": \"Mustermann\",\n" +
                    "\t\t\"category\": {\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"id\": " + categoryId + "\n" +
                    "\t\t}, \"partOfOrgUnit\": {\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\"id\": " + companyId + "\n" +
                    "\t\t}\n" +
                    "\t}\n" +
                    "}"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"SUCCESS: Contact added successfully\"}")));
    }
}
```

My persistence xml, with the two databases:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="sab_pu">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/projectdb?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="sab_test_pu">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/testdb?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is my .properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/testdb?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.SAB.test.testsController.TestContactController':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mvc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations:{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34756569/3641067

Comment: as stated above, I tried that, but it just ignored the settings in the .properties file

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure. I'm kinda new to this and I wanted to use the MocMvc to perform my rest request. By removing the @AutoConfigure it doesn't work anymore. Should I configure it on my own instead of letting spring do it for me?

Comment: Ok, but then how do I configure it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have the possibility to use Spring Boot? It offers you a 'plain' Servlet-based deployment into a already existing Tomcat instance, too. My last plain Spring sessions are too fare away.

I can give you an example for Nikos answer with Spring Boot and assume that you'r using Maven.

In Spring Boot its possible to configure most things with a `application.properties` file. This includes the setup for a `persistence.xml` file, too.

For your productive environment create a `application.properties` file in `src > main > resources` with content like this.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/projectdb?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The test environment needs a file named `application-test.properties` with this content.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/testdb?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

As you can see, for `test`ing you don't need to repeat everything, just the stuff which changed.

Now you can test your application to run in productive mode by just starting the application. In your console you should see that Spring Boot uses MySQL. If you want use your testing setup add `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` as JVM parameter.

After this steps, let's switch to your JUnit test which looks like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.profiles.active=test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MeTest {
    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The `@SpringBootTest` sets the current profile to `test` and starts the JUnit test run.

This is just one possible way for your problem. I hope it helps you and everything works because I have no MySQL database on my working machine.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot and did what you suggested, hower after removing the "@AutoConfigureMockMvc" annotation I get the following exception(see edited question). How should I configure the mockmvc?

Comment: Does it work if you add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to the JUnit test? I updated my example.

Comment: nope, if i add that it doesn't run on the test database anymore

Comment: I implemented quick and dirty an example where I use H2 database for testing purpose. In this example I'm able to store an entity with Spring Data and call a REST service with MockMvc, Do you use my `application.properties` examples to configure the database?

Comment: ok, i managed to configure the mockmvc based on my controller and it worked. Thanks alot!