# Spring Boot JNDI not found - can't compile WAR with Maven

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, jndi

i can't mvn clean install my project.
I need to use a remote JNDI in WAR(not jar), but having the name in application.properties throws error during mvn clean install(due to "datasource jndi name not found")

---

if I have to use jndi name from a remote server, that I have no control over, how do i compile my package in WAR without lookup fail, but let it look up during the deployment/installation of the app on the server? any hint, or direction is very much appreicated...

---

in app prop, i have

**spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/ff-app**

I have tried: [Spring boot JNDI datasource lookup failure - Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479263/spring-boot-jndi-datasource-lookup-failure-name-comp-env-jdbc-not-found-in-con)

tried, http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource

and pretty much every questions asked in stackoverflow about a remote jndi..

Some of the errors:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/ff-app'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
>       ... 69 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/ff-app'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource(JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9509801a.CGLIB$dataSource$0() ~ ........

My POM.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: are you using any JUNit test? If so.. try to compile by using maven and excluding tests

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment.  I do not have any custom test, but i am using the default tests. If JUNit is included by the default, could you tell me how to exclude it? I assume that's done in pom.xml..

Comment: Try to add the following in pom.xml (in properties tag):  `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
<maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>`

Comment: It was letting me compile. I did little bit of search, and it seems like those options are skipping the mvn unit test. Is it safe/common to use  this  in pom for spring boot deployment?

Comment: well usually when I need to create an artifact it means I already executed my tests so I would say it's safe but it also depends on your scenario. There can be some scenarios where you want to create the artifacts and also execute JUNit tests

Comment: Well, this absolutely solved my problem. I deployed the app and it worked on the remote server. Much thanks to you. Although, I am still a bit confused why mvn JUnit test was throwing an error OR if it is a common issue, why it was not listed in spring boot reference guide.. If you still have time, could you explain briefly why or what might have been an issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that when you try to compile by using maven, maven tries to execute also Junit tests; in your case you have in src/resources/java some unit tests and so maven tries to execute them. Since you are using a JNDI datasource, it means that also the servlet container must be active for executing tests otherwise you can't get connection.

In this case when maven tries to execute tests maybe no servlet container (and, so, no JNDI datasource) is active and your test throws error.

To solve this (and to compile the maven artifact) you must:

- or exclude tests execution: this is done by adding `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>` in pom.xml. No test will be executed
- or ignore tests error this is done by adding `<maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>` in pom.xml. In this case tests will be executed but any test error will not stop maven compilation

The configuration I gave not only tells maven to not execute tests but it tells maven to not stop on any test error

I hope i have been clearer... my english is not the best

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarity. I also found this(maybe related to the problem i had): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756264/spring-boot-with-datasource-when-testing